# Missing perl modules error for properly installed perl modules on FreeBSD 8.3, perl 5.16

Tags: freebsd, perl

Trying to run a Nagios plugin on 8.3-RELEASE-p3, I get the error:

```
Missing perl modules: Net::SMTP::SSL
```

I have rebuilt the ports for both p5-Net-SMTP-SSL and perl5.16. `cpan -i Net::SMTP::SSL` reports

```
Net::SMTP::SSL is up to date (1.01).
```

The plugin calls /usr/bin/perl in the shebang (which is correct per my path) and invokes the module via

```
push @required_module, 'Net::SMTP::SSL' if $ssl;
```

What else should I be looking at?

Comment: If you type `which perl`, does it return `/usr/bin/perl`? if you run `/usr/bin/perl -MNet::SMTP::SSL -e exit`, do you get any errors? Does `/usr/local/bin/perl` exist?

Comment: `/usr/bin/perl -MNet::SMTP::SSL -e exit` was the command I needed here - thanks for the perl noob help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per larsks's comment, running `/usr/bin/perl -MNet::SMTP::SSL -e exit` turned up a few other missing modules one at a time:

```
# /usr/bin/perl -MNet::SMTP::SSL -e exitCan't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.16/BSDPAN /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16/mach /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16 /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.16/mach /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.16 .) at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 17.BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 17.Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16/Net/SMTP/SSL.pm line 8.BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16/Net/SMTP/SSL.pm line 8.
Compilation failed in require.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

Installing the p5-IO-Socket-SSL and p5-Net-SSLeay fixed the problem.